# Ventura 13.5.2 update broke apache & virtual hosts configuration?

Tags: apache, homebrew, virtualhost, httpd.conf, macos-ventura

Months ago, I followed precisely [that guide](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-ventura-apache-multiple-php-versions) to install and configure Apache & PHP using homebrew. Also [that one](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-ventura-apache-mysql-vhost-apc) to install MySQL and configure some virtual hosts I need to develop websites (with dnsmasq). Everything was perfectly working before the last Ventura update (13.5.2). Now, accessing my vhost url displays "It Works!" but *I can't access to my local vhost files*. It looks like it ignores the DocumentRoot setting in the vhost configuration...  Moreover, a "ps aux" command shows that httpd is still ran as _www or root, disregarding of the setting I set in /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf.

I already double checked every setting, and I still can't understand why it displays "It Works" and not the files in my vhost folder.

Could you help me to understand what's wrong ??

Thanks !

R.

**/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf :**

```
ServerRoot "/opt/homebrew/opt/httpd"
Listen 80
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule authn_file_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule dir_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User myname 
Group staff
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin my@email.com
ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
...
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/homebrew/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/opt/homebrew/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    ...
</IfModule>

Include /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

**/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@email.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/myfolder"
    ServerName myfolder.local
    ServerAlias www.myfolder.local
    ErrorLog "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/myfolder/error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/myfolder/access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/myfolder">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@email.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/myotherfolder"
    ServerName myotherfolder.local
    ServerAlias www.myotherfolder.local
    ErrorLog "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/myotherfolder/error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/myname/Documents/Sites/myotherfolder/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**After having rebooted my computer, or after having successfully run 'brew services restart httpd', https is _www and not by myname/staff :**

```
myname@MacBook 2.4.57_1 % ps aux | grep httpd        
_www              3188   0,0  0,0 408788960   3808   ??  S     9:01     0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www              3179   0,0  0,0 408788960   3872   ??  S     9:00     0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www               832   0,0  0,0 408799200   3936   ??  S     6:12     0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www               472   0,0  0,0 408788960   3824   ??  S     6:08     0:00.03 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root               151   0,0  0,0 408657952   6288   ??  Ss    6:07     0:00.57 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
myname              6134   0,0  0,0 408626896   1296 s000  S+    9:58     0:00.00 grep httpd
```

**myfolder.local resolves correctly :**

```
myname@MacBook 2.4.57_1 % ping www.myfolder.local
PING myfolder.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.200 ms
```

I tried almost everything, and still get "It works" when I access to myfolder.local in my browser. I'm expecting to see content of my index.php file...

**EDIT. WOW... ** I found out that I had to stop builtin apache and unload it using

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

then I restarted 'brew services restart httpd' and saw using 'sudo lsof -i:80' that httpd now runs as myname. That solved my problem...